# Differences in JavaScript OO methodology

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn more about JavaScript OO Programming, but am seeing conflicting methods to create a "Class"-like object. I am wondering if there are any substantial differences in these two methods:

**Method 1**

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;

    this.setName = function(val){
        this.name = val;
    }

    this.getName = function(){
        return this.name
    }
}

var John = new Person("John");
```

**Method 2**

```
function Person(name){
    var exports = {};
    exports.name = name;

    exports.setName = function(val){
        this.name = val;
    }

    exports.getName = function(){
        return this.name
    }

    return exports;
}

var Bob = Person("Bob");
```

I have seen these two methods used for creating a complex JavsScript object.  I have even seen large JS plugins like jQuery use method 2 instead of method 1 to set up their jQuery functions.  Is one of these faster or more efficient than the other in any way?

Comment: `var exports = new Object();` makes me sad.

Comment: @AlienWebguy You should explain why rather than making unhelpful comments.  This is a good potential teaching moment!

Comment: Well, it's better and easier to create an empty object with `{}`.

Comment: Please explain why using `var exports = new Object();` is bad and why it is that I see that method used to create objects all over

Comment: Method 2 looks like a pattern (factory?) for producing objects

Comment: So are there advantages to using one or the other? Because they appear to have the same functionality in terms of organizing properties and methods into OO syntax

Comment: @MattHintzke second method has its advantages too, look up "factory design pattern" i.e. http://javascript.info/tutorial/factory-constructor-pattern

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one creates an object of the type `Person`, while the second one creates an object of the type `Object`. The first one allows you to add members to the prototype of `Person`.

You can put all the functions in the prototype instead of creating new functions for every instance:

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype = {
  setName: function(val){
    this.name = val;
  },
  getName: function(){
    return this.name
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! My second question would then be, is using the prototype property to assign new functions to the object better than just the simple `this.myFunc = function(){}`?

Comment: @MattHintzke The `prototype` allows you the ability to define each method once for all instances to inherit. Placed inside the `function` (constructor or factory) directly on the object, it will be redefined for each. At times, per-instance definitions can certainly be useful, but in general they can be a waste.

Comment: Also, I have heard that is is always better to append to the prototype like `Person.prototype.setName = function(){}` rather than assigning it again like you did above? Does this really matter? Or do that only affect it if `Person` was inherited by another object

Comment: @MattHintzke Don't try to make generalizations like "it's always better to do x" etc, there's always exceptions, and there's always other ways to accomplish the same goals that aren't necessarily better or worse, *just different*. Understand what the code does, then decide what will work best for your particular case.

Comment: @MattHintzke: Javascript doesn't have inheritance out of the box, so that is usually accomplished by setting a base object as the prototype. In that case you would append to the prototype of the child object and not replace it. Otherwise it's just a matter of taste, and what works with how you arrange your code.